# Unable to run Expo bare workflow Web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web

I already have a bare workflow app developed that runs for IOS and Android. Now, I want to run the app on the web.

When I try to run using "yarn run web", I get errors that start with "Module not found: Can't resolve"

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../assets/Icon/Home/switchViewIcon.png'
  58 |           >
  59 |             <Image
> 60 |               source={require('../../assets/Icon/Home/switchViewIcon.png')}
     |                      ^
  61 |               style={{ height: 25, width: 25, padding: 10 }}
  62 |               hitSlop={{ top: 12, bottom: 12, left: 12, right: 12 }}
  63 |             />
./node_modules/@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication/lib/index.js:24
Module not found: Can't resolve './AppleButton'
  22 |
  23 |
> 24 | export { default as AppleButton } from './AppleButton';
  25 |
  26 | /**
  27 |  * iOS
./resourceConfig.js:15:11
Module not found: Can't resolve './assets/Icon/Home/switchViewIcon.png'
```

This is what my package.json looks like

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@expo-google-fonts/mulish": "^0.2.2",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.3",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.10.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "14.11.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^14.11.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.7.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^14.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^14.8.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.10.4",
    "eas-cli": "^0.49.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.4",
    "expo-device": "^4.1.1",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.14.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.3",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "geofire-common": "^5.2.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-art": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-instantsearch-native": "^6.12.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "https://github.com/ppoom/react-native-dropdown-picker.git",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.3",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.1.23",
    "react-native-inset-shadow": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-orientation-loading-overlay": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.9",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-read-more-text": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-switch-toggle": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.6",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-native": "^6.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.1",
    "prettier": "2.5.0"
  },
  "postinstall": "npx patch-package",
  "private": true
}
```

This is what my index.js looks like

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

Do I need to configure anything extra?

Answer (score 0):

It because

```
source={require('../../assets/Icon/Home/switchViewIcon.png')}
```

on the

```
<Image
> 60 |               source={require('../../assets/Icon/Home/switchViewIcon.png')}
     |                      ^
  61 |               style={{ height: 25, width: 25, padding: 10 }}
  62 |               hitSlop={{ top: 12, bottom: 12, left: 12, right: 12 }}
  63 |             />
```

not found the switchViewIcon.png you can make sure the source or path is correct

Comment: Path is definitely correct, but still complains.